# How to Show All Domain Users & Their Group Membership (Active Directory)

Tags: powershell, vbscript, active-directory

I would like to find a way (VB Script or PowerShell preferably) of generating a report which displays all user accounts on the domain, and displays the groups of which they are a member.

I would like this to be exported to a Excel spreadsheet in the following format:

> Username1 | Group1, Group 2, Group 3, Group 4, Group 5 etc.
>   Username2 | Group1, Group 2, Group 3, Group 4, Group 5 etc.

I have been playing around with Quest Powershell Commands for AD and came up with the following:

```
get-qaduser * -sizelimit 0 | select Name,MemberOf | export-csv report.csv
```

However this displays in the output file as:

```
Username1 | System.String[]
Username2 | System.String[]
Username3 | System.String[]
```

Where `System.String[]` should be the group names.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, you need to join the group names:

```
$memberOf = @{n='MemberOf';e={ ($_.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1') -join ';' }}

Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 | `
Select-Object Name,DN,SamAccountName,$memberOf | `
Export-Csv report.csv
```

Comment: Thanks very much Shay. Works an absolute treat, I can then de-limit this using semi-colon to put them in to separate columns as well. Is there a way of reversing the script so it shows groups and members of those groups, like this:

Group1 | User1, User2, User 3 etc.

etc.?

Comment: Yes, try this: Get-QADGroup -sl 0 | select Name,DN,@{n='Members';e={ ($_ | Get-QADGroupmember | select -expand name) -join ';'  }}

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this script (Not tested):

```
$users = get-qaduser * -sizelimit 0 

$a = @()

foreach ( $user in $users)
{  $al = New-Object System.Object

$al | Add-member -type Noteproperty -name Accountame $user.samaccountname
$al | add-member -type Noteproperty -name Groups $user.memberof

$a += $al

}

$a | export-csv report.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, but this returns "System.String[]" in place of where the groups should be displayed, also. I believe Shay has provided a script which works, many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
get-qaduser * -sizelimit 0 | select -Property @{N="my";E={$_.name}}, -ExpandProperty MemberOf | export-csv report.csv
```

Comment: Tried this and received: Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'MemberOf'. At line:1 char:36. Thanks for your help but I believe Shay has provided a way of doing this :-)